# require_relative and utility methods

Tags: ruby, module, nomethoderror

I wanted to separate some methods into a module for abstraction purposes but I am getting a nomethod error when testing the first function in my module.

**functions.rb**

```
module Functions

  def avg_ticket(vol,count)
    (vol.to_f/count).round(2)
  end

end
```

**example.rb**

```
require_relative 'functions'
vol = 5000
count = 2500
avg_ticket = Functions.avg_ticket(vol,count)
```

I am getting a `undefined method 'avg_ticket' for functions:Module (NoMethodError)`

both files are in the same folder so I am using `require_relative` if that makes a difference. this may be basic, but can anyone help me understand why the method is undefined here?

**edit:** changed `module functions` to `module Functions` in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named your module `functions`, but you're trying to call `Functions`.  Names are case sensitive.  Also, you need to name your module with an upper case first letter anyway.  Also, to be defined on the module itself, you want to use `def self.avg_ticket`, see the following:

```
module Functions

  def self.avg_ticket(vol,count)
    (vol.to_f/count).round(2)
  end

end
```

And using it:

```
p Functions.avg_ticket(2, 25)
> 0.08
```

Comment: ah i did have the module capitalized in my code, typoed the module name when i added the question here, I was missing the self in my version, works now, thank you for your help. is there a way to only call the method name when using the module in a program or do you always have to use Functions.avg_ticket?

Comment: If you [include it in another class](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm) you can call it how you want.